# ¿Por qué solamente me representa la segunda gráfica?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, matplotlib, jupyter

Estoy aprendiendo OOP. Como ejercicio intento crear una clase que me muestre la gráfica de varios indicadores de varias cotizaciónes. Para ello hago:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

class ImportadorCotizaciones:

    def __init__(self, tickers ):
        self.start = "2017-1-4"
        self.end = "2021-5-30"
        self.retornos = pd.DataFrame({})
                
    def importar_cotizaciones(self):        
        stocks = web.DataReader(tickers,
                                'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
        self.retornos = stocks.pct_change()

class CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo:
    def __init__(self, cotizaciones):
        self.cotizaciones = cotizaciones       
        self.N = 255          # 255 días de bolsa en un año
        self.rf = 0.01         # 1% tasa libre de riesgo
        self.Sharpe_Anual = []
        self.sortino = []
        self.max_drawdowns = []
        self_ratio_calmars = []
    
    def normalizar_pct_cambio(self):
        print (f"\nEl gráfico muestra el crecimiento de 1€ invertido desde el {self.cotizaciones.start} hasta el {self.cotizaciones.end}") 
        (self.cotizaciones.retornos + 1).cumprod().plot()

        
    def calcular_sharpe_anualizado(self):              
        mean = self.cotizaciones.retornos.mean() * self.N - self.rf
        sigma = self.cotizaciones.retornos.std() * np.sqrt(self.N)
        Sharpe = mean / sigma
        self.Sharpe_Anual = (252**0.5) * Sharpe
        self.Sharpe_Anual.plot.bar()
        plt.show()
       
        
tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT', 'GOOGL','FB'] 
cotizaciones = ImportadorCotizaciones(tickers)
cotizaciones.importar_cotizaciones()

graficos_indicadores = CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo(cotizaciones)
graficos_indicadores.normalizar_pct_cambio()
graficos_indicadores.calcular_sharpe_anualizado()
```

Si solamente ejecuto el primer método (`graficos_indicadores.normalizar_pct_cambio()`), muestra la gráfica correctamente
Si ejecuto los dos métodos

```
graficos_indicadores.normalizar_pct_cambio()
graficos_indicadores.calcular_sharpe_anualizado()
```

Solamente muestra la gráfica del segundo. ¿Cuál puede ser la causa?.

Comment: no sé python, pero viendo el código por encima, que llames al mismo objeto, por lógica reemplazaría a los datos que tenga anteriormente, no?

Comment: Intento practicar en la OOP, la inyección frente a la herencia, de ahí la utilización del objeto. El objeto cotizaciones, me devuelve los " retornos", parámetro necesario en los dos métodos que calculan los parámetos que quiero graficar.

Comment: como pones de etiqueta `jupyter` mas que seguro que lo estas ejecutando ahi, si tienes ambas instrucciones en la misma celda solo se mostrara la segunda (al menos eso pasa con Google Colab), pon cada una en celdas separadas

Comment: Efectivamente, llamando a cada método en una celda diferente no hay problema.

Comment: ¿Por qué quiero hacerlo así?. Si en una celda integro todas las clases creadas, y al final crero los objetos y llamo a los métodos, la salida será como un informe, con todas las devoluciones, una a continuación de otra.

Comment: Me falta finalizar cada método con plt.show()